# Beginning SQL How do I sum and pick columns in the same line?

Tags: sql

I just started learning SQL on w3schools.com today, and want to make sure I'm on the right track.

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Write a SQL statement finding the combined population of the U.S. and Mexico (in this database).

I can't post the table here because of lack of reputation, but it is very simple. You are given that Mexico's country ID is 2 and U.S. id is 5.

the table has 4 columns, CITY_ID, NAME, COUNTRY_ID, and POPULATION. You do not know how many rows there are. So basically I need the to add up the POPULATION columns that have a corresponding '2' or '5' country ID.

This is what I have so far:

```
//this statement gives result-set with all the cities in Mexico and the U.S.
SELECT * FROM City
WHERE country_id=’5’
OR country_id=’2’

//here, I don't know how to reference the result-set
SELECT SUM(population) FROM result-set
```

The question also says to do it in one statement, is there a simpler way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You put the `SUM(population)` expression into the query..

```
SELECT SUM(population) AS TotalPopulation
  FROM City
 WHERE country_id='5'
    OR country_id='2'
```

Note that you can also write the `x=a or x=b` as `x in (a,b)`, i.e.

```
 WHERE country_id in (5,2)
```

(you can also drop the quotes if country_id is integer although it won't fail with them)

Comment: @Scorpi0 Wow thanks guys did not realize I would get an answer so fast!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(population)
FROM City
WHERE country_id=’5’
OR country_id=’2’
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there.

```
SELECT Sum(population) FROM City
WHERE country_id=2
OR country_id=5
```

I assume the country id is integer so speechmarks are not needed